# Pushing mouse click location to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick, getelementbyid

I'm trying to push the coordinates of a mouse click on a particular element to the end of an array. This is what I have:

IN THE HEAD:

```
var seatsArray = [];
```

IN THE BODY:

```
var coordinates = document.getElementById("image");
coordinates.onclick = function(event) {
  seatsArray.push(offsetX, offsetY);
}
document.write("Seats array contains: " + seatsArray + ".");
```

Probably something simple, but I'm new to javascript, so I'd appreciate any help as to why it isn't working!

Thanks

Comment: "coordinates" relative to what? The start of the document, the "image" element, the viewport?

Comment: Relative to the element with id "image". Thanks

Comment: distance from it's center or from its edge? You could be more specific when you ask.

Comment: Sorry, i meant pixel coordinates from the top left corner. Roki's global code in the Answer looks perfect, however nothings showing up in the array when I document.write? I explained a bit more in the comments below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I see, alter your on click event to this:

```
coordinates.onclick = function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (!window.event) { // thanks firefox
    event.offsetX = event.layerX;
        event.offsetY = event.layerY;
  } 
  seatsArray.push(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
}
```

Firefox offsetX/Y is layerX/Y, and ie have a global event object.

But if you wnt global cordinates try this:

```
coordinates.onclick = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;

if (e && e.pageX && e.pageY) {
            e.posX = e.pageX;
            e.posY = e.pageY;

        } else if (e && e.clientX && e.clientY) {
            var scr     = {x:0,y:0},
                object  = e.srcElement || e.target;
            //legendary get scrolled
            for (;object.parentNode;object = object.parentNode) {
                scr['x'] += object.scrollLeft;
                scr['y'] += object.scrollTop;
            } 
            e.posX = e.clientX + scr.x;
            e.posY = e.clientY + scr.y;
        } 
 seatsArray.push(e.posX, e.posY);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. Still seems not to be pushing to the array as the document.write outputs only the text I specified and no coordinates when I click the image.

Thanks

Comment: Global script looks perfect, however, still no array output from document.write. Might it be to do with the fact that the "image" element is zoomable and panable (<img onLoad="shiftzoom.add(this);" id="image".......>)?

Thanks

Comment: @IceDragon: You're issuing `document.write` calls in your `click` handler?

Comment: RM, The document.write is not in the click handler.

Comment: @IceDragon: ok so you're issuing the `document.write` call after you've *attached* the click handler. The array is empty at that point. You have to actually physically click on stuff to get the array populated.

Comment: Try don't use document.write, print positions with a method, it's more w3c frendly:
function printPositions(el) {
   var result = "Seats array contains: ";
   for (var i = 0, len = seatsArray.length; i < len; i+=2) {
       result += seatsArray[i] +' , '+ seatsArray[i+1] + '<br/>';
   }
   seatDiv = document.createElement('div');
   seatDiv.innerHTML = result; 
   el.appendChild(seatDiv);
}

Comment: omg how stupid of me, document.write can't write text after the page is loaded. Do you know how I can get the text to change to display the array AS i click the "image" element, without reloading the page? I don't actually need to implement this in my final script, I just want to see that the array is working and see how its output changes as I edit it. 

Thanks

Comment: @IceDragon: change the `document.write` to `alert`.

Comment: That doesn't work because the alert just comes up when the document loads, and doesn't display again. Thanks

Comment: @IceDragon: **move your debugging code into the code you're trying to debug**. In other words, alert *inside* the click handler.